# How to fireEvent outside of ConsumeEvent function in icCube web-reporting

Tags: javascript, events, iccube

i would like do a simple fireEvent("Refresh","")

from javascript outside of consumeEvent function.

as i want to be able to do a setinterval that would fireEvent "Refresh"
and put the event name inside a table 'do refresh query' in the web reporting

so eventually the table will refresh itself every 1 minute for example.
(i want to be able to refresh every table i have in the dashboard separately with different time interval)

the problem is that i'm able to do fireEvent only from the consumeEvent function
and then use context.fireEvent("Refresh","") but this can happen every time i have a different event occurring from the dashboard and it's not good enough

Answer (score 1):

Event could be thrown anywhere with context's event manager instance:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     context.eventMgr().fireExternalEvent("eventName", eventValue)
</script>
```

Also you can fire events if you have access to ic3Reporting instance:

for example:

```
var ic3Application = ic3.startReport(options);
```

In that case you can fire app events in such way :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //get ic3application instance
    var ic3Application = ic3.startReport(options); 

    setInterval(function(){
       ic3Application.fireEvent('table1-refresh', {})
    },60000)

    setInterval(function(){
       ic3Application.fireEvent('table2-refresh', {})
    },120000)
</script>
```

Then just set event names to "do Refresh Query" tables' event.

**UPDATE**

Version of script inside ic3report.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var ic3root = "../" 
        var ic3rootLocal = "../" 

        var options = {
            root: ic3root,
            rootLocal: ic3rootLocal,

            callback: function () {
                $('#intro').remove();

                  var options = {
                            <!-- ic3-start-report-options (DO NOT REMOVE - USED TO GENERATE FILES) -->
                  };
                  var ic3Application = ic3.startReport(options);
                  setInterval(function () {
                     ic3Application.fireEvent('ic3-table', {})
                  },20000)
            };

        ic3ready(options);
</script>
```

### UPDATE

Here is a [report](https://demo6.iccube.com/icCube/doc/ic3report?name=%2Fshared%2FStackOverflow%2FDifferent%20Refreshing%20Intervals&ic3demo) with an example.

Comment: Hey i'm getting console error "VM457:109 Uncaught ReferenceError: context is not defined(…)" and if i'm using ic3Application i'm getting "VM698:110 Uncaught TypeError: ic3Application.fireevent is not a function". the question is how to define access to the instance?

Comment: As far as javascript is case sensitive, "ic3Application.fireevent" should be "ic3Application.fireEvent"

Comment: i tried ic3Application.fireEvent and also ic3Application.fireExternalEvent and i get the same error

Comment: I'm using the new icCube Web Reporting : 6.0.1

Comment: Could you clarify please, is the third code block looks the same as in an answer above and it still doesn't work?

It strange, because
`var ic3Application = ic3.startReport(options);
   setInterval(function () {
      ic3Application.fireEvent('ic3-table', {})
   },20000)` works fine on my side. 

As far as you have 109 line for context error and 110 line for ic3Application error, I can only guess that you are using code from the first answer's code block next to `ic3.startReport(...)`, but actually it's not a good idea, because context just could not be available at this moment.

Comment: I've put    ***var ic3Application = ic3.startReport(options); 

    setInterval(function(){
       ic3Application.fireEvent('table1-refresh', {});
    },60000)

    setInterval(function(){
       ic3Application.fireEvent('table2-refresh', {});
    },120000)*** inside the 'configuration' javascript. when i run the report get error "referenceError: ic3Application is not defined
 /icCube/doc/ic3report:112"  i've tried to put in the html embedded ic3report.html file the script but i get ic3 is not define... any suggestions?

Comment: @ItayRegev could you please give me version of the web-reporting you are using, you can get it under "Admin"  -> "Version" of the reporting menu.

Comment: icCube Reporting : 6.0.1 (3794)

Comment: I've also done what you wrote in the update. like ic3Application.fireEvent('ic3-table', {caption: "1"}). but when i try to use it in the report i use @{ic3-table:caption} i get "missing value". i also tried ic3Application.fireEvent('ic3-table', "1") and use @{ic3-table} and still get "missing value" :( So i don't think the fireEvent was happening at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129927/discussion-between-artem-lopatiy-and-itay-regev).

Comment: any new development in this issue?